# Disable all visual effects in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, effects

How do I disable all effects in Ubuntu  15.10?

I already called this on the console:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

But it doesn't seem to have a great effect, When I open the Ubuntu dash, it still gently fades in.

How can I disable all effects, so I minimize the usage for my graphic card?

I know, there are more lightweight solutions like Lubuntu or Xubuntu, but I would like to stay on plain Ubuntu.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are some you can disable using the unity-tweak-tool.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Run:

```
unity-tweak-tool &
```

Click on **Launcher** (in the **Unity** section) and in the **Launcher** tab:

- set **Auto-hide** to `off`
- set **Urgent animation** to `No animation`
- set **Launch animation** to `No animation`
- set **Icon backgrounds** to `No colouring`.

In the **Search** tab:

- set **Background blur** to `off`.

Click on the **Overview** button at the top to go back to the main menu.

Click on **General** (in the **Window Manager** section).  In the **General** tab:

- set **Desktop magnification** to `off`
- set **Texture quality** to `Fast`
- set **Window Animations** to `off`.

Additionally, you can turn off more animations in ccsm.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run:

```
ccsm &
```

In the **effects** category, untick all of the boxes.

In the **accessibility** tab, untick all of the boxes.

There are probably more you could disable in compiz as well.

Comment: `compizconfig-settings-manager` is quite dangerous, I ended up with a desktop without any window decorations. I could only repair this by disabling "Composite" an re-enable "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"

Comment: @rubo77 well of course you need the Ubuntu Unity Plugin as unity *is* only a compiz plugin and nothing more silly. There is nothing dangerous it's all completely fixable.

Comment: @rubo77 also, you *should* be able to have composite enabled but change slow animations to disabled

Comment: It seems like the setting "enable low graphics mode" in the Unity Plugin settings seems to solve a slow unity dash

Comment: @rubo77 i  don't think you understand, *slow animations* will actually slow animations down when enabled.

Comment: I Understand, but the dash stays animated (on `<Super>` key), no matter which settings I try. so the low graphics mode seems the best we can get.

Comment: This already helps a lot, but the menu (that opens when you hit the Windows key) still fades in. Any place I can disable that?

Comment: @Jorn try turning "background blur" off using unity-tweak-tool >  search > background blur

Comment: @Jorn additionally, for unity-tweak-tool go to general > Animations > Window Animations off

Comment: @Jorn or for ccsm , go to Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > General and set Background Color to black, set Dash Blur to no blur, and there is a "low graphics mode" option as well but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to install the compiz configuration manager and disable them, be warned that you have a possibility of breaking the system, it def works though (not sure if it works on 15.10) but is generally found in the Ubuntu software center. However give this a try for the temrinal.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open up a terminal and type sudo ccsm, click effects then uncheck animations and fading windows.

You can muck around with a lot of other things in there as well provided you know what you are doing

Comment: What in Your answer is new? I think that is already said in the accepted answer

Comment: Sorry was a bit careless and tired and didnt read the 2nd alternative mentioned, it happens