# Can't play Dota 2

Tags: drivers

I run a dual boot pc with windows 7 and ubuntu 16.04 running an intel core i5(4th gen) processor with 8 GB ram and intel HD graphics 4400.

Now Dota 2 runs just fine on windows but lags like hell on ubuntu. I think it might be because i haven't installed any drivers.

Consider me a novice so avoid any unstable drivers which might break something.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems related to FPS. I also have Intel graphics. The main problem is related to the compositor. Try disabling the compositor and run Dota again, you will notice a much better performance. On the other hand, try to reduce the render quality and the video options of the game.

For information about disabling compositing, read this thread:

[Disable compositing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689602/disable-all-visual-effects-in-ubuntu-15-10/689612)

Enjoy!